# Error al restaurar backup en sql server

Tags: sql-server

estoy intentando restaurar una base de datos pero me genera el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede solucionar?

Comment: Qué has investigado?

Comment: Verifica que el usuario con el que estas accediendo a la ruta de la BD tenga permisos (no el usuario de la BD; el usuario en sesión desde donde quieres cargar el respaldo hacia donde lo estas tomando). Prueba poniendo el archivo en ruta **donde todos puedan accesarlo sin restricciones**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más probable es que tu respaldo esté corrupto. Por la ruta, supongo que es para una base de datos de pruebas. Genera otro respaldo e intenta de nuevo. También es importante que revises la integridad de la base de datos antes de generar el respaldo usando el comando `DBCC CHECKDB`.

Si estás tratando de recuperar una base de datos productiva, lo mejor será que busques a un consultor experto que te ayude a recuperar la mayor cantidad de información posible.

Comment: Gracias crack, al parecer si esta dañado